# OOP in Laravel 5.4

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5.4

in my project, I create this ugly controller which returns a view with bootstrap table filled with data.

and I'm wondering how can I move table sort in other class and pool it whenever I need it?

This is my controller now:

Request current link:

```
$link = http_build_query();
```

Request current sort order:

```
$price = request('price');
```

Check in which order it is sorted and return opposite:

```
$price == 'DESC' ? $price = 'ASC' : $price = 'DESC';
```

Return view:

```
return view('view', compact('price', 'link'));
```

And in view I use it like this:

```
<a href="/buyer/bid/all?{{ $link }}&price={{ $price }}">Price</a>
```

Comment: Quibble: That ternary should really be `$price = $price == 'DESC' ? 'ASC' : 'DESC'`.